# Load JSON as a resource in HTML to avoid bootstrap ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Often, when creating single page apps, you need to populate the app with some form of data (i.e. in the json-format). This is usually done through an AJAX-call.

Now, this isn't the best possible solution. The DOM needs to be loaded before the AJAX call is launched, and it's semantically awkward to do this async through javascript.

Is it possible to load a JSON-resource in the same fashion as a `<script src="some-file.js">` automatically fetches `some-file.js`, or  fetches some-image.png automatically when the DOM loads?

Comment: `Now, this isn't the best possible solution.` I would argue that it is. `The DOM needs to be loaded before the AJAX call is launched, and it's semantically awkward to do this async through javascript.` I don't see how it's awkward. In jQuery, it can be as simple as 1 line of code.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but some-file.js: `data = { "data"} ;`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I am speaking on a more general level. Why is bootstrap data not considered a resource in the way an image or css file is considered a resource? why should it have to wait to be loaded until everything else is in place?

Comment: @user234461 - typically, the bootstrapped data comes from a web service or API-like interface.

Answer (score 3):

The correct MIME type for JSON is `application/json`

It is possible to include it in the JSON file, as a script. If the path is relative, just use this code

```
<script type="application/json" src="path/to/json/file.json"></script>
```

I would disagree, however, that this is semantically awkward. Simply load it with `$.getJSON`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) What I mean by semantically awkward is that this data is a resource in the same way an image is a resource or a javascript file is a resource. Why should not data be loaded as a resource as well?

Comment: For one, it will delay the loading of the page. This will load synchronously. If you load it using AJAX, it will load the JSON resource after the DOM has finished loading.